# Change int variable pointed by pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I am a little bit newbie, and pointers still do troubles to me. I would like to change value of `int`, which I get from parameter (as a pointer) in function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool function(int* a){

    a++;

    printf("%d",*a); //getting some big number, maybe address. If i did not use a++; I get just normal a, unchanged.

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try to use (*a)++ instead!

Comment: Why are you incrementing the pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're incrementing the pointer (not the value pointed with it) in the statement `a++`. If you want to increment the value of the parameter, you should dereference it first:

```
(*a)++; //instead of a++;
```

Printf is not printing exactly an address, is just printing the value of the integer (may be an integer, can be something else) stored next to your parameter `a`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dereference the pointer to get the actual value of the integer (not address) by using `*a`. Then you can increment that value. So your code should be `(*a)++` instead of `a++` (In your case you are just incrementing the address and trying to access the next location in memory).

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is a variable which contains the address in memory of another variable. We can have a pointer to any variable type.

**The indirection or dereference operator `*` gives the contents of an object pointed to by a pointer.**

**The unary or monadic operator `&` gives the address of a variable.**

In your program you increment the pointer `a`:

```
 a++;
```

That operation does **NOT** affect the object to which pointer points.

If you want to increment the value of the parameter, you should dereference pointer with the dereference operator `*` and then increase the value.

```
(*a)++;
```

This is a small example how in practice you can change the value of the variable by having a pointer to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int* a){

    (*a)++;          // dereference the pointer `a` and increase the content of an object pointed to by the pointer by 1.
    (*a) = (*a) + 2; // dereference the pointer `a` and increase the content of an object pointed to by the pointer by 2.

    printf("\nprint from function (*a) = %d\n",(*a) ); 
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 7;
    int *p = &x;             // pointer to variable x 

    printf("x = %d\n", x );  //     x = 7

    function(p); // calling with pointer p as argument

    printf("x = %d\n", x );  //    x = 10

    function(&x); // calling with pointer &x as argument  

    printf("x = %d\n", x );  //    x = 13       

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x = 7                                                                                                               

print from function (*a) = 10                                                                                       
x = 10                                                                                                              

print from function (*a) = 13                                                                                       
x = 13
```

Answer (score 1):

do `(*a)++` instead.
Your function receives a pointer as an argument. If `++` is used with a pointer variable then, for 64 bit int variable, it will increment to 4 byte and will hold that memory address, if there is no value in that location then a garbage value will be printed out which why you are getting that large number. Follow [this link](https://www.javatpoint.com/pointer-arithmetic-in-c) to have a basic idea about pointer arithmetic.